# New product type based on bundle - price type not saving

Tags: magento-1.9, bundle-product

I've created new product type extended from bundle product.
Every thing works fine, except "price_type" "sku_type" attributes.
I want to save the price_type as fixed "it's value is 1", also for the sku_type.
But it's not saving this value, In other words those attributes not saving at all, not fixed nor dynamic. 
Where should I look for the solution?
I've debuged the data sent by observer before_save and the values sent successfully, but it's not saved to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by set the price_type in the type model in "afterSave" Method